# After another page is loaded in a div, no control is working, giving error

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, html, state

I'm using div instead of iframe to call a page but as soon as the other page loads in div then after clicking on any button, or selecting radiobutton, these events give this error[image]

This is how I load div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#result').load('frmChatRequest.aspx', function () {

            });
        }, 10000);
    });

</script>
```

This is frmChatRequest.aspx.cs page

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                dt_chatRequest = LookupChat.getPendingRequestInMyChat("",Int64.Parse(_objSession.LoginID), _objSession, _errMsg);
                ClsDataBind.DoGridViewBind(gdvChatRequestRoom, dt_chatRequest, _errMsg);
                myMarqueeChatRequest.InnerText = "You Have  " + dt_chatRequest.Rows.Count.ToString() + " new chat request/s in your rooms in last 15 minutes";
            }


        }
 protected void gdvChatRequestRoom_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Accept")
        {


            HiddenField hdn = ((HiddenField)gdvChatRequestRoom.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("hdnAddPeople"));
            string strHdnValue = hdn.Value;
            //Button btn = ((Button)gdvChatRequestRoom.Rows[0].Cells[3].FindControl("btnAccept"));
            //string strBtnID = btn.ID;
            string strBtnID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

            string query = "select * from Q116 where Q116002="+strBtnID+ " and Q116001="+  hdn.Value ;
            _objQ116.SelectAll(query);
            _objQ116.Q116DF2 = _objSession.LoginID;
            _objQ116.Update(_objQ116.Q116DF2);
            _objQ116.SelectAll(query);
            _objQ116.Q116004 = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss");
            _objQ116.Update(_objQ116.Q116004);



            //insert in Q119

           // _objQ116.Update(Q116004);
            //_objLOG2.SelectAll(query);
            //DateTime dt1 = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(5.5);
            //string str = dt1.ToString();
            //_objLOG2.Update(str);
            //Write code to add to card
        }
        if (e.CommandName == "Reject")
        {
            HiddenField hdn = ((HiddenField)gdvChatRequestRoom.Rows[0].Cells[0].FindControl("hdnAddPeople"));
            string strHdnValue = hdn.Value;
            //Button btn = ((Button)gdvChatRequestRoom.Rows[0].Cells[3].FindControl("btnAccept"));
            //string strBtnID = btn.ID;
            string strBtnID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            string query = "delete from Q116 where Q116001=" + hdn.Value + " and Q116002=" + "'" + strBtnID + "'";

           // _objQ116.SelectAll(query);
            Educity.EduDB.Select(query);
            //Write code to add to card
        }
        Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
    }
```

Comment: It depends on what frmChatRequest.aspx is serving up to the client...ideally it should be serving back partial html only, or JSON/XML data. If its serving up a whole html page, it won't render in your browser as expected...

Comment: @deostroll I have added extra information inthe question

Comment: It looks like you need a new design. Why did you move away from the iframe approach?

Comment: @deostroll Because whenever iframe loaded it blinked,flickered a lot

Comment: the answers here right now are good suggestions...alternatively you can use an updatepanel in the frmChatRequest.aspx page; the gridview will reside inside it; the updatepanel's `UpdateMode` property need to be set to `Always`. After all this, you can use this page in an iframe...the flickering will be avoided

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET webforms JavaScript and markup is probably messing up the hosting page and this is why a whole page is normally loaded in an iframe.

Have you considered using custom controls? They are really easy and encapsulate functionality into objects that can be included in any web page. It looks like frmChatRequest would be better as a control. Building a custom control is very similar to building a aspx webforms page, but it can then be re-used.

For more info on custom controls see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.ASPX